# Download Image from url and show in listview

Tags: android

I'm fetching title,data and url of the image. I'm storing url of the image in an arraylist. Now I want to download the images from these urls and show them in list view. I've tried multiple codes but none of them worked. If any of them can share any code snippet that would by really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: What are you currently using, which you are saying not working, please share the code

Comment: I'm not using any library right now. Just simple Adapter with text views  using async task

Comment: You must use a library, Picasso/Glide/Volley. Stil if you don't want to use them, share the code for downloading the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this two ways:

1.Picasso

Add below library in gradle

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

Code :

```
Picasso.with(this).load("url").into(imageView);
```

2.Glide Library

Add below library in gradle

```
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
```

Code to Set

```
Glide.with(this).load("url").into(imageview);
```

Answer (score 1):

Import [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) Or [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) in you're project :

Code for Picasso :

```
Picasso.get().load("url").into(imageView);
```

Code for Glide :

```
Glide.with(this).load("url").into(imageView);
```

All you have to do is import one of library and set image to imageholder in listview. Make sure you put condition while putting image to imageView.

Something like :

```
if(url != null){
    Picasso.get().load("url").into(imageView);
}else{
    Picasso.get().load(/*add any drawable or blank*/).into(imageView);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For showing Images in ImageView or ListView you can use Picasso and Glide library.

In Picasso like this:

```
Picasso.with(activity).load(ImageUrl).into(holder.productimage);
```

and in Glide like this:

```
Glide.with(this).load("url").into(imageView);
```